# Electron.js loadfile does not load

Tags: electron

I have an electron app that when the window is ready it loads a login page. It then receives the credentials via an `ipcRenderer.send` and I then run this code:

```
ipcMain.on('login', async (event, u, p) => {
    let result = await login(u, p)

    switch (result) {
      case 200:
        console.log('I am before loadfile') // test message to see if code runs
        mainWin.loadFile('./index.html')
        console.log('I am after loadfile') // test message to see if code runs
        break;

      default:
        mainWin.loadFile('./login.html')
        break;
    }
  })
```

Now... this code does not return any error, and I can see in the console the test messages before and after the instruction, but I don't understand why `index.html` does not load. The funny thing is... it DOES load sometimes, but most of the times it doesn't...
Both main and renderer processes are error free.

It seems as though the instruction is simply ignored for some reason. Except that it isn't ALWAYS ignored.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You only use "electron ." for testing this, or? when you later have to package your app, this will not work anymore anyway. you need to use an absolute path. you can create an absolute path by using __dirname

Comment: @welcor thank you for your comment. It works now, so that's great. I still don't understand why it would "sometimes" work the way I had it earlier though... but that's ok... it bothers me but I can live with it :)

Comment: when something only works sometimes, it sounds to me like a racing condition. This can happen when you use async await code but do not await it. add a console.log to your default case to see if that suddenly overrides the case 200.

Comment: I wasn't using async/await code because my login function is currently a placeholder for the actual function that I will be using in real life. I have changed it to an async function (and I await for it) to check if it made any difference, but it didn't. But you are right as what seems to have fixed the problem is wrapping the loadfile instruction with a setTimeout(). It's not very elegant and I'm not sure if there is a better way to manage this, but it does work

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Welcor (read comment below) creating an absolute path with `__dirname` fixed the problem.

*** edit ***
Untrue. It made me believe it worked... but after a while it started doing the same as before... i.e. it only works SOMETIMES...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).